# Problem of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have the function $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n e^{-x}}{n!}$ and a sequence that is defined by $u_{n}=f_{n}(n)$. Additionally, I find that $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}\le e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$ with the precedent question. Now, I must deduce that $u_{n} \le e^{-1-\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n-1})}$. I don't understand how to demonstrate, please help me

Comment: $u_n\leq e^{1-\frac{1}{4(n-1)}}u_{n-1}\leq e^{1-\frac{1}{4(n-1)}}\left(e^{1-\frac{1}{4(n-2)}}u_{n-2}\right)\leq\ldots$

Comment: why i didn't think to this before ... thank you :)

Comment: $u_n$ is a sequence, not a series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's a joke of Google translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll see what I can do directly.

$u_n
=\frac{n^n e^{-n}}{n!}
$.
Since we are interested in
$e^{...}$,
let $v_n 
= \ln u_n
=n \ln n - n - \ln n!
$.

By Stirling's theorem,
$\ln n!
=n \ln n - n +\frac12 (2\pi n)+\frac1{12n}-\frac1{360n^3} + ...
=n \ln n - n +\frac12 (2\pi n)+\frac1{12n+c(n)}
$,
with the error being less than
the last term omitted,
so that
$0 < c(n) < 1$.

So

$\begin{align}
v_n
&=n \ln n - n - \left(n \ln n - n +\frac12 \ln(2\pi n)+\frac1{12n+c(n)}
\right)\\
&=-\frac12 \ln (2\pi n)-\frac1{12n+c(n)}\\
&=-\frac12 \ln (2\pi)-\frac12 \ln( n)-\frac1{12n+c(n)}\\
\end{align}
$

So $u_n
=e^{v_n}
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
e^{-(12n+c(n))}
$

You can use
$\ln n < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}
< \ln(n+1)
$
to get $u_n$
in the form the problem wants,
and this makes it easy to prove the result
in an elementary manner.

As to the estimate for
$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$,

$\begin{align}
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}
&=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1} /(e^{n+1}(n+1)!)}{n^n /(e^{n}n!)}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1} }{e(n+1)n^n}\\
&=\frac{(1+1/n)^{n} }{e}\\
\end{align}
$

and this can be estimated in many ways.

The easiest might be

$n\ln(1+1/n)
=n(\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3} ...)
=1-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{3n^2} ...
$
so

$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}
=e^{-1/(2n)+1/(3n^2)-...}
$
and this is why the
true constant is
$\frac12$ instead of $\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But I don't learn the Stirling's theorem, and I send a mail to the teacher who has ask to do this work,  there is no error in the question. Also the answer should be simple because I should deduce uniquely with the precedent result (that is $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \le e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$)